# Theme-specific TextView appearances not always working

Tags: android, themes, android-3.0-honeycomb

I've got this rather peculiar issue. I'm using the default Android appearances to style my `TextView`s, and all but one seam to be working flawlessly.

The appearance I'm using is `?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall`, and it's changing the font color without any issues when I'm in the layout XML designer and change the theme between `Holo` and `Holo.Light` (Android 3.0+).

However, one particular `TextView` won't be styled when it's running on the tablet, and it's using the exact same XML code as the others, that are working.

Here's my XML code for the `TextView` that doesn't work:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" 
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
    android:lines="2"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall">
</TextView>
```

I've also tried doing it in code using the following method, but that doesn't work either:

```
setTextAppearance(this, android.R.attr.textAppearanceSmall);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd like to point out that when styling more then one `View`-component with the same style (by using XML), there is the very neat way of [creating Styles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) for that.

So your Style might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- The Style for all the TextViews -->
    <style name="TextViewStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_alignParentBottom">true</item>
        <item name="android:layout_alignParentLeft">true</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width=">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">2sp</item>
        <item name="android:lines">2</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">top|center</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

While your Layout only looks like this:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" 
    android:text="TextView"
    style="@style/TextViewStyle"
/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" 
    android:text="Another TextView"
    style="@style/TextViewStyle"
/>

<!-- .... -->
```

This makes the code much more maintainable and helps preventing typos.

---

Last but not least, something similar to your problem has already been discussed [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1727). This might help solving your problem, too.

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful and fixed my problem. I am now using setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Small instead. Cheers!